# No unique index found for id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-6

I have faced an error **"No unique index found for id"** while trying to use Upsert all. But isn't ID a unique index by default? Initially we have created our application in rails 3 and now we have migrated it to rails 6. Is this issue related to the migration?

I have added the below migration and it works fine

```
def change
  add_index :order_lists, :id, unique: true, algorithm: :concurrently
end
```

Comment: Depends on how you created the `id` column on that table in the first place or how you did the migration.

Comment: I don't think you should add such an index on the primary key, as it is unique by default. Here is some more context on the similar Rails issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40059